# Datos del Checkbox

Tags: html5, checkbox

Mi duda creo que es sencilla.

Tengo un formulario con 150 registros.

Puse un checkbox, la Función es marcar cuales de las líneas del formulario son validas.

esta sería la  linea de código  del checkbox

```
<td><label> <input type="checkbox" name="corren[]" value="no"   ></label></td>
```

El problema que tengo y es fundamental es que el formulario recibe solo los datos de los checkbox marcados y no el de todos los registros.

Por lo cual la información no me sirve para nada.

Pues necesito saber cuales estan marcados y cuales no.

No encontré nada sobre esto.

Y si por este metódo no se puede hacer, me gustaría saber que otro metódo serviría

Muchas Gracias

Comment: El problema es que quieres cuando chequeas algun checkbox obtengas los valores de esa fila?

Comment: Claro, si yo marco la fila 5 y 6 en el formulario siguiente me lo muestra como 1 y 2 . Yo necesito que me mande los datos positivos y negativos para no perder la referencia. Sino tendria que usar un select, y eso me haría perder mucho tiempo de trabajo

Comment: Ok a ver si te entiendo necesitas capturar cuales estan chequeados y cuales no para no perder la referencia?

Comment: Si es eso exactamente